# Solveability of a circuit(schmitt trigger)

Tags: schmitt-trigger

I was reading about Schmitt triggers and something is bothering me. Given that each component is memoryless- shouldn't the circuit be solvable(as in, for any input voltage it should always be immediately at a steady-state)?

Why can't it be described by a set of time independent algebraic equations since the V/I relationships of all components in the circuit are time independent?

Answer (score 5):

A Schmitt trigger is not a memoryless circuit. It has positive feedback, which is one way of implementing state (or memory).

Similarly, a flip-flop can be made from only NAND gates, even though the individual gates would be considered "memoryless" when used individually. Again, it's feedback that gives the overall circuit its "memory".

Comment: or from NOR gates.  that's the easiest, most direct RTL using BJT.

Comment: The saturation of a transistor results in significant base charge storage; it is the base capacitance of the saturated transistor that contains the 'memory' of the two-transistor Schmitt.